# Winamp - Google talk Tweak deletes m3u file

Tags: google-talk, winamp

I'm using Winamp and Google Talk in daily life. When I'm trying to set my current track in Winamp as music status, Google Talk freeze and crash. To avoid that, I've followed the following tweak [showed in the blog post](http://www.sankaranand.com/blog/2008/01/google-talk-freezes-with-show-music-status-using-winamp-55/).

However I noticed that Winamp keeps deleting that file within few days, (which I can predict). I tried to keep above file in *read only* attribute. But in this state, it started to crash Google Talk as usual.

How to keep this tweak intact without repeating it so often?

Comment: So the file gets deleted on a schedule? *Something* must be triggering the deletion, since it doesn't happen every time you use Winamp or GTalk. If you can figure out what the trigger is, maybe you can shut it down. Otherwise look into file permissions. It might be possible to tweak them such that Winamp (or whatever's to blame) no longer has access to the file.

Comment: I don't think it's like schedule. But I can't reproduce that on particular schedule. After this question, still file intact. I'll update status very soon if anything change. File Permissions are normal.